# CompareTo() method doesn't work

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparer

I have a Class named Person which implement `IComparable<int>` generic Interface . I have a  generic list which contain Person Object and I assign my list to an array and I'm sorting the list but I'm taking the follwing error.

> error: {"Failed to compare two elements in the array."}

this is my Person class

```
public class Person : IComparable<int> 
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(int other)
        {
            return Age.CompareTo(other);
        }
    }
```

and this program cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> list2 = new List<Person>();

        list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 80 });
        list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 45 });
        list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 3 });
        list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 77 });
        list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 45 });

        Person[] array = list2.ToArray();
        Array.Sort(array);

        foreach (Person item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Age);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: the error is in Sort method

Comment: You have to implement `IComparable<Person>` to use it on an array of `Person`.

Comment: Why do you convert to an Array? Just iterate over the List<Person> while using [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: You could implement IComparer if you wanted, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your class to this:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person> 
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        return Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
    }
}
```

If you create class with `IComperable<int>` you are able to compare it with int, not with the same class.
You have to pass to the template the same class/struct as one you are comparing with.

Comment: @downvoters, This was one of those times where it might have been appropriate to edit some code and add that space between Person and other

Comment: You should probably explain *why* this works and what the OP was doing wrong for this to be a complete answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your generic to `Person` since you are comparing Person to Person, and not Person to int:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }


        public int CompareTo(Person other)
        {
            return Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
        }
    }
```

Also, you do not need to cast to an Array afterwards, you can keep it as a list:

```
List<Person> list2 = new List<Person>();

            list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 80 });
            list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 45 });
            list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 3 });
            list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 77 });
            list2.Add(new Person() { Age = 45 });

            list2.Sort();

            foreach (Person item in list2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Age);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Person other)
        {
            return this.Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
        }
    }
```

Your custom comparer is wrong! CompareTo() method returns an integer which indicates:-

```
 0 -> Current instance is equal to the object being compared.
>0 -> Current instance is greater than the object being compared.
<0 -> Current instance is less than the object being compared.
```

When you call `Array.Sort(array);` you are actually passing an array object but the problem is you had implemented `IComparable` of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `Icompareable<Person>` as the other answer states or you can implement `IComparable` like:

```
public class Person : IComparable
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(int other)
    {
        return Age.CompareTo(other);
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Person otherPerson = obj as Person;
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;
        else
        {

            return Age.CompareTo(otherPerson.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use LINQ to order your List like:

```
foreach (Person item in list2.OrderBy(r=> r.Age))
```

Comment: thanks @user2711965 but I want to implement generic interface